# I have one menu and sub menu's but I am not able to access sub menu but i want to access sub menu for appropriate menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my CSS and my sub menu is displaying from left side I want that sub menu should slide up and down

```
   .outer
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: Gray;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.g_logo
{
    width: 20%;
    color: White;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-family:st @Gulim;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.g_home
{
    width: 15%;
    color: Black;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-family:@Gulim;
}
.g_services
{
    width: 15%;
    color: Black;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-family: @Gulim;
}
.g_achvmnt
{
    width: 14%;
    color: Black;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-family: @Gulim;
}
.g_cnct
{
    width: 15%;
    color: Black;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-family: @Gulim;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.g_home_items
{
    margin-left: 28%;
    background-color: Purple;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
.g_services_items
{
    margin-left: 42%;
    background-color: silver;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
      border-radius:5px;
}
.g_achvmnt_items
{
    margin-left: 57%;
    background-color: Purple;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
.g_cnct_items
{
    margin-left: 72%;
    background-color: AppWorkspace;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
```

This my Jquery

I am not able to retrieve my sub menu please help me to get access my sub menu when I am mouse hover my menu. sub menu appears but I cannot access that sub menu

```
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
                    </script>
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $(".g_services_items").hide();
                            $(".g_services").hover(function () {            
                                $(".g_services_items").toggle("slow");
                            });


                        });
                    </script>






 **HTML FILE this is my HTML coed plzzz help me for this**




                    <body>
                        <form id="form1" runat="server">
                        <div class="outer">
                            <div class="g_logo">
                                LOGO
                            </div>
                            <div class="g_home">
                                HOME
                            </div>
                            <div class="g_services">
                                SERVICES
                            </div>
                            <div class="g_achvmnt">
                                ACHIEVMENTS
                            </div>
                            <div class="g_cnct">
                                CONTACT US
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="g_services_items">
                            <li class="mega first haschild">
                                <ul class="megamenu level1">
                                    <li class="mega first"><span class="menu-title">T-shirts</span></li>
                                    <li class="mega"><span class="menu-title">Sport shoes</span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </div>

                        </form>
                    </body>
```

Comment: please edit your question and post your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didnt post your css so i dont know where and how your submenu appears, but this issue is quite common.

you hover mouse over 'services' and sub menu appears, but it disappears when you try to click anything on the submenu.

basically you could make your submenu stay by doing the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".g_services_items").hide();
       $(".g_services, .g_services_items").on("mouseover",function () {
           $(".g_services_items").stop().show("slow");
       });
        $(".g_services, .g_services_items").on("mouseleave",function () {
           $(".g_services_items").stop().hide("slow");
       });
   });
```

you can check how it works [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/Kk3ne/1/)

explanation:

- you dont toggle the sub menu, you show() and hide() it.
- you show the menu when mouse hovers over the 'services' or over the submenu,
- you hide the sub menu when mouse is not over neither 'services' or the submenu.
- the .stop() function here meant to avoid misbehavior, because the show() and hide() animations have to complete before the other one starts, so you have to stop them in the middle on ever action.

EDIT:

your menu appears from the left because you have set

```
.g_services_items
{
    margin-left: 42%;
    float: left;
}
```

remove those two properties and set the submenu left: to the left: of the 'services' using jQuery:

see new example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/Kk3ne/2/)

Comment: replace with what? if you by 'replace' you mean replace it with my example, then yes you can :)

Comment: Yes It works my frnd thnk you so much n also my sub menu when appears it comes from left side there is also some problem can you plz check that out?????????????????????

Comment: i have updated my answer :) if it helps, please accept this answer by clicking the green V on the left side

Answer (score 0):

This is what u can try with hide and show , mouse over and leave

```
    $(".g_services_items").hide();
     $(".g_services").hover(function (e) {            
     $(".g_services_items").show("slow");
                        })
    $(".g_services_items").hover(function () {            
                            $(this).show("slow");
                         }).mouseleave(function(){
                         $(this).hide();
                         })
       });
```

here is the live : [LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UfGaJ/)